# How to autohide YUI2 Menu on blur?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui2

I have a `YAHOO.widget.Button` of the type "menu". My task is simple: The menu is shown when the user clicks on the button, and is hidden when the user clicks elsewhere on the screen.

Here's my code on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tRssn/

What I've tried so far:
 1. Setting the `clicktohide` property of the Menu widget to true (see above code)
and
 2. Subscribe to the blur event on the Button/Menu widget and close the menu if it's visible.

Approach 1 doesn't work for some reason and approach 2 works with IE and Mozilla, but not Chrome.

Shouldn't there be an easy way to do this?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to solve this by explicitly creating a YAHOO.widget.Menu object, rendering it, and then assigning it as the menu to the YAHOO.widget.Button object.

http://jsfiddle.net/tRssn/1/

Strangely, I have to set the config for the Menu widget like this instead of at the time of the creation:
`oButton.getMenu().cfg.config.clicktohide.value = true;`